# How to set seekbar unmovable using kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

How to set seekbar widget unmovable using kotlin language in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

```
//kotlin
mySeekBar.enabled = false;
```

```
//java
mySeekBar.setEnabled(false);
```

This will block it from moving and it will be frozen